# Wolfram Alpha result for infinite series summation .

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, wolfram-alpha

Consider the infinite sum $s=1+1/2^2-1/3^2-1/4^2+1/5^2+1/6^2-...$. We can see that the series is absolutely convergent and hence convergent. But WolframAlpha seems to give me a different answer. When I add two more terms it shows me that the series converges. Can anyone explain why this happens and also give an analytical expression for the sum ?[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Ask Wolfram Alpha! What are your own efforts to find the limit?

Comment: If you plug in some values of $n$ in the sum expression under "result" you'll see that WA misunderstood how you wanted the series to continue (which I assume was $++--++--\cdots$).

Comment: @Karl I have no clue how to begin. Any hint will be useful in getting me started .

Comment: @Karl Despite whatever Stephen Wolfram may claim, I don't think Alpha is capable of answering questions like this. I think "why is my calculator giving me a different answer than the one I already know to be true" is a perfectly valid question for SE, and one that demonstrates prior effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wolfram alpha guessed your general term wrong. If you look at the cell titled "Result", you see the general term
$$\frac{-54-(-7+n)n(16+(-7+n)n)}{n^2}$$
instead of what you intended.

Try instead [inputting the sum directly](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum[%28-1%29%5En%281%2F%282*n%2B1%29%5E2%2B1%2F%282*n%2B2%29%5E2%29%2Cn%3D0..infinity]).

We can compute the sum explicitly by computing four related sums using Wolfram alpha:
$$
\begin{align*}
S_0 &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}, \\
S_1 &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{i^n}{n^2} = -\frac{\pi^2}{48} + Ci, \\
S_2 &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2} = -\frac{\pi^2}{12}, \\
S_3 &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-i)^n}{n^2} = -\frac{\pi^2}{48} - Ci,
\end{align*}
$$
where $C$ is Catalan's constant.
The sum we are after is
$$
\left(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}i\right)S_1 + \left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}i\right)S_3 = \frac{\pi^2}{48} + C.
$$

Comment: But the input interpretation cell is correct. That's what is confusing. Anyway, is there a way to compute the sum analytically ?

Comment: @SrinivasK There are many many ways to fill in more terms in any sequence. If we just know the first three terms are "1, 2, 3", the next term should be 4, right? Not if I wanted the sequence defined by $a_1 = 1$ and $a_n = a_{n - 1} + \lceil \frac{n}{3} \rceil$. That's why the input cell was fine, but why WA didn't use what you expected: It added up a sequence with the same first 6 terms, but it wasn't the same sequence. Summing the reciprocal squares is a very hard problem, it probably will take finesse to find the sum you're looking for analytically.

Comment: @SrinivasK Explained how to compute the sum.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{n\geq0}\left(-1\right)^{n}\left(\frac{1}{\left(2n+2\right)^{2}}+\frac{1}{\left(2n+1\right)^{2}}\right)=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{\left(2n+2\right)^{2}}+\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{\left(2n+1\right)^{2}}=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n+1}}{n^{2}}+C=\frac{1}{4}\eta\left(2\right)+C$$
 where $C$
  is the Catalan constant and $\eta$
  is the Dirichlet eta funcion. Using the identity$$\eta\left(s\right)=\left(1-2^{1-s}\right)\zeta\left(s\right)$$
  with $$\textrm{Re}\left(s\right)>1,$$
  and $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function we have$$\eta\left(2\right)=\frac{1}{2}\zeta\left(2\right)=\frac{\pi^{2}}{12}$$
 so$$\sum_{n\geq0}\left(-1\right)^{n}\left(\frac{1}{\left(2n+2\right)^{2}}+\frac{1}{\left(2n+1\right)^{2}}\right)=\frac{\pi^{2}}{48}+C.$$